# assigning member function to be other function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Can a function be assigned or alter its definition, just like overriding a function by derived classes.

But at this time, it is out of scope from the class.

I mean like this:

```
//class.h

class MClass
{
public:

  void function(); // this is the function I am referring to.
}
//class.cpp

void MClass::function() { }

//file1.cpp
MClass mclass;


void globalFunction() { }

mclass.function = globalFunction; //is this even possible?
```

Comment: yes, but not like that

Comment: What are you trying to achieve or what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @hmjd well I am making this button object and  I want just make it very simple to use. Thus assigning a function to what the button does makes it very simple to use for me :)

Comment: @ACB No, it is not what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `function()` is a real function, you want `function Callback` instead.

see sample program: [on ideone](http://ideone.com/I68JQ1)

```
#include <functional>
class MClass
{
public:
  std::function<void(void)> func_ptr;

  void setFuncPtr(const std::function<void(void)>& ptr)
  {
    func_ptr = ptr;
  }

  void callFuncPtr()
  {
    func_ptr();
  }
};
```

You could set `func_ptr` to any callabe objet

```
MClass m;
m.setFuncPtr(globalFunction);   // set to standalone function
m.callFuncPtr();

// set lambda to it
m.setFuncPtr([](){ std::cout << " do something " << std::endl; });
m.callFuncPtr();
```

Or bind to other object

```
 struct Test
 {
   void print() { std::cout << "Test::print" << std::endl; }
 };
Test t;
m.setFuncPtr(std::bind(&Test::print, t));
m.callFuncPtr();
```

You could also pass parameter to function by using std::bind and placeholders.

Comment: which is the fastest and better implementation there?

Comment: callable objects suppose to be faster than functions, compiler can inline the code.

Comment: do you `#include <functional>` ?

Comment: how to define `void (MClass::*fpFunction)(void)` in cpp file?

Comment: @mr5 how do you mean? it's a pointer, you just need to bind it to a function or callable object.

Comment: at `class.cpp` how am I gonna define it. I do it like `void class::function() { }` and put me on error.

Comment: @mr5: you do not *define an attribute*.

Comment: does binding a function make a new copy of that function?

Comment: Yes, or you could do copy by ref. `m.setFuncPtr(std::bind(&Test::print, std::ref(t)));`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways :

- c++03 - you can use function pointer :

  ```
  class MClass
  {
  public:

    void (*function)();
  };
  void globalFunction()
  {
    // ...
  }

  MClass obj;
  mclass.function = globalFunction;
  ```
- in c++11 you can use functors :

  ```
  class MClass
  {
  public:

    std::function<void()> function;
  };
  void globalFunction()
  {
    // ...
  }

  MClass obj;
  mclass.function = globalFunction;
  ```

Comment: yea your c++11 example is called a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper and informally called a functor (not to be confused with the math term).

Comment: my std library don't have that std::function and std::bind. I am using msvs 2010 professional edition.

Comment: @mr5 you have to include `<functional>`. I am pretty sure they have these in msvc 2010

Comment: @ecatmur Right, my mind was somewhere else when I wrote it. Fixed now

Comment: yeah I miss to include it.

Comment: any disadvantages of using `void (*fpFunction)(void);`? It is quite simple and don't include any libraries.

Comment: @mr5 That is a function pointer. As such, it can point only to functions and static methods.

Comment: C++03 can use `boost::function`.